# How to declare variable or constant of some type in Coq?

Tags: coq

How to declare variable or constant of some type in Coq? The first chapter of Software Foundations does not make this clear. Should I use Parameter clause. I am implementing object logic in Coq and I would like to declare my first fact - John.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are asking for, but in any case, here is my answer that tries to answer the spirit of the question:

```
Definition one: nat := 1.
```

This creates a constant called `one` with value `1`.

`Parameter`, as far as I understand, is used to record postulates of your theory, [as the Coq manual says](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html?highlight=parameter#coq:cmd.parameter).